# How to use Spark Structured Streaming with Kafka Direct Stream?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I came across [Structured Streaming with Spark](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/07/28/structured-streaming-in-apache-spark.html), it has an example of continuously consuming from an S3 bucket and writing processed results to a MySQL  DB.

```
// Read data continuously from an S3 location
val inputDF = spark.readStream.json("s3://logs")

// Do operations using the standard DataFrame API and write to MySQL
inputDF.groupBy($"action", window($"time", "1 hour")).count()
       .writeStream.format("jdbc")
       .start("jdbc:mysql//...")
```

How can this be used with [Spark Kafka Streaming](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html)?

```
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  ssc,
  PreferConsistent,
  Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
)
```

Is there a way to combine these two examples without using `stream.foreachRDD(rdd => {})`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there a way to combine these two examples without using
> `stream.foreachRDD(rdd => {})`?

Not yet. Spark 2.0.0 doesn't have Kafka sink support for Structured Streaming. This is a feature that should come out in [Spark 2.1.0 according to Tathagata Das](https://youtu.be/rl8dIzTpxrI), one of the creators of Spark Streaming.
[Here is the relevant JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SPARK-15406).

### Edit: (29/11/2018)

Yes, It's possible with Spark version 2.2 onwards.

```
stream
  .writeStream // use `write` for batch, like DataFrame
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "brokerhost1:port1,brokerhost2:port2")
  .option("topic", "target-topic1")
  .start()
```

Check this [SO post(read and write on Kafka topic with Spark streaming)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53250208/1592191) for more.

### Edit: (06/12/2016)

Kafka 0.10 integration for Structured Streaming is now [expiramentaly supported in Spark 2.0.2](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html):

```
val ds1 = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
  .option("subscribe", "topic1")
  .load()

ds1
  .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .as[(String, String)]
```

Comment: is there a way to track the progress feature? E.g. a Jira story, a feature request, etc.?

Comment: @ike_love Yes, you can find it [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SPARK-15406)

Comment: Please refer to the following Documentation for (Kafka)Alpha release : http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html

Answer (score 3):

I was having a similar issue w.r.t reading from Kafka source and writing to a Cassandra sink. Created a simple project here [kafka2spark2cassandra](https://github.com/ansrivas/spark-structured-streaming), sharing in case it could be helpful for anyone.

Comment: @Sokia - your project worked great, clean and self contained. Thanks.