# No Parallelism with Custom Spark Structured Streaming Sink

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am writing a Custom Spark structured streaming sink to write events read from Kafka to Google BQ(Big Query). Below is the code that I have written.

The code is compiling and running successfully. But My Sink is always running in only one executor (always where the driver program runs). I do not understand the issue here.

Here is the implementation of my custom Big Query Sink.

```
package bq

import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.Sink
import org.apache.spark.sql.sources.{DataSourceRegister, StreamSinkProvider}
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.OutputMode


class DefaultSource extends StreamSinkProvider with DataSourceRegister{

  override def createSink(
                           sqlContext: SQLContext,
                           parameters: Map[String, String],
                           partitionColumns: Seq[String],
                           outputMode: OutputMode): Sink = {
    new BQSink(sqlContext, parameters, partitionColumns, outputMode)
  }

  override def shortName(): String = "bq"
}
```

```
class BQSink(sqlContext: SQLContext,
                  parameters: Map[String, String],
                  partitionColumns: Seq[String],
                  outputMode: OutputMode) extends Sink {


  override def addBatch(batchId: Long, data: DataFrame): Unit = {

    val df = data.sparkSession.createDataFrame
                       (data.sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(data.collect()), data.schema)
   
    df.collect().foreach({ row => {
      //code that writes the rows to Big Query.
    }  
  }
```

Here is my driver program

```
 // Reading raw events from Kafka
    val inputDF = sparkSession.readStream
                              .format("kafka")
                              .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", config.getString("kafkaBrokers"))
                              .option("subscribe", "topic")
                              .option("fetchOffset.numRetries", 5)
                              .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
                              .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
                              .load()
                              .selectExpr("value")
                              .as[Array[Byte]];

    // Transforming inputDF to OutputDF
    val outputDF = inputDF.map(event => transform(event))
                          

    // Writing outputDF events to BQ
    val query = outputDF.writeStream
                        .format("bq")
                        .option("checkpointLocation",config.getString("checkpointLocation"))
                        .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
                        .start()

    //Start Streaming
    query.awaitTermination()
```

Even though my topic has multiple partitions, My Custom sink is running in a single executor only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `df.collect` will collect all data from the executors to your driver. Therefore you are seeing only the driver sending data to your sink.

You need to do `df.foreachPartition` and use a BQ producer that is accessible on your executors. You may run into "Task not serializable" issue but you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590592/how-to-write-spark-streaming-df-to-kafka-topic/39539234#39539234) to understand how this can be solved in Scala Spark.